# file name too long when using Ansible command module

Tags: ansible, chef-habitat

I am trying to install chef automate using chef habitat with ansible.

here is the related section of main.yml

```
- name: get aib filename
    find:
      paths: /home/ec2-user
      file_type: file
      use_regex: yes
      patterns:
        - '^automate.*'
    register: file_automate

  - name: deploy chef-automatev2
    command: "sudo chef-automate deploy '/home/ec2-user/config.toml' --accept-terms-and-mlsa --skip-preflight --airgap-bundle '/home/ec2-user/{{ file_automate.files }}'"
```

but getting error:

> TASK [deploy chef-automatev2]
>   ***************************************************************************fatal: [10.1.1.2]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["sudo",
>   "chef-automate", "deploy", "/home/ec2-user/config.toml",
>   "--accept-terms-and-mlsa", "--skip-preflight", "--airgap-bundle",
>   "/home/ec2-user/[{uuid: 0, uwoth: False, umtime: 1540882069.3233995,
>   uinode: 82, uisgid: False, usize: 605693959, uisuid: False, uisreg:
>   True, upw_name: uroot, ugid: 0, uischr: False, uwusr: True, uxoth:
>   False, uislnk: False, unlink: 1, uissock: False, urgrp: True,
>   ugr_name: uroot, upath: u/home/ec2-user/automate-20181020020209.aib,
>   uxusr: False, uatime: 1540882068.8493989, uisdir: False, uctime:
>   1540882074.7854095, uisblk: False, uwgrp: False, uxgrp: False, udev: 64768, uroth: True, uisfifo: False, umode: u0644, urusr: True}]"],
>   "delta": "0:00:00.026909", "end": "2018-10-30 06:48:00.362616", "msg":
>   "non-zero return code", "rc": 94, "start": "2018-10-30
>   06:48:00.335707", "stderr": "Error: DeployError: Unable to install,
>   configure and start the service: Failed to unpack airgap artifact:
>   Failed to open install bundle file /home/ec2-user/[{uuid: 0, uwoth:
>   False, umtime: 1540882069.3233995, uinode: 82, uisgid: False, usize:
>   605693959, uisuid: False, uisreg: True, upw_name: uroot, ugid: 0,
>   uischr: False, uwusr: True, uxoth: False, uislnk: False, unlink: 1,
>   uissock: False, urgrp: True, ugr_name: uroot, upath:
>   u/home/ec2-user/automate-20181020020209.aib, uxusr: False, uatime:
>   1540882068.8493989, uisdir: False, uctime: 1540882074.7854095, uisblk: False, uwgrp: False, uxgrp: False, udev: 64768, uroth: True, uisfifo:
>   False, umode: u0644, urusr: True}]: open /home/ec2-user/[{uuid: 0,
>   uwoth: False, umtime: 1540882069.3233995, uinode: 82, uisgid: False,
>   usize: 605693959, uisuid: False, uisreg: True, upw_name: uroot, ugid:
>   0, uischr: False, uwusr: True, uxoth: False, uislnk: False, unlink: 1,
>   uissock: False, urgrp: True, ugr_name: uroot, upath:
>   u/home/ec2-user/automate-20181020020209.aib, uxusr: False, uatime:
>   1540882068.8493989, uisdir: False, uctime: 1540882074.7854095, uisblk: False, uwgrp: False, uxgrp: False, udev: 64768, uroth: True, uisfifo:
>   False, umode: u0644, urusr: True}]: file name too long",
>   "stderr_lines": ["Error: DeployError: Unable to install, configure and
>   start the service: Failed to unpack airgap artifact: Failed to open
>   install bundle file /home/ec2-user/[{uuid: 0, uwoth: False, umtime:
>   1540882069.3233995, uinode: 82, uisgid: False, usize: 605693959, uisuid: False, uisreg: True, upw_name: uroot, ugid: 0, uischr: False,
>   uwusr: True, uxoth: False, uislnk: False, unlink: 1, uissock: False,
>   urgrp: True, ugr_name: uroot, upath:
>   u/home/ec2-user/automate-20181020020209.aib, uxusr: False, uatime:
>   1540882068.8493989, uisdir: False, uctime: 1540882074.7854095, uisblk: False, uwgrp: False, uxgrp: False, udev: 64768, uroth: True, uisfifo:
>   False, umode: u0644, urusr: True}]: open /home/ec2-user/[{uuid: 0,
>   uwoth: False, umtime: 1540882069.3233995, uinode: 82, uisgid: False,
>   usize: 605693959, uisuid: False, uisreg: True, upw_name: uroot, ugid:
>   0, uischr: False, uwusr: True, uxoth: False, uislnk: False, unlink: 1,
>   uissock: False, urgrp: True, ugr_name: uroot, upath:
>   u/home/ec2-user/automate-20181020020209.aib, uxusr: False, uatime:
>   1540882068.8493989, uisdir: False, uctime: 1540882074.7854095, uisblk: False, uwgrp: False, uxgrp: False, udev: 64768, uroth: True, uisfifo:
>   False, umode: u0644, urusr: True}]: file name too long"], "stdout":
>   "\nInstalling artifact", "stdout_lines": ["", "Installing artifact"]}

and if i use:

```
 - name: deploy chef-automatev2
    command: "chef-automate deploy config.toml --accept-terms-and-mlsa --skip-preflight --airgap-bundle {{ file_automate.files }}"
```

i get error:

> TASK [deploy chef-automatev2]
>   **************************************************************************** fatal: [10.1.1.20]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd":
>   ["chef-automate", "deploy", "config.toml", "--accept-terms-and-mlsa",
>   "--skip-preflight", "--airgap-bundle", "[{uuid:", "0,", "uwoth:",
>   "False,", "umtime:", "1540883970.2111344,", "uinode:", "83,",
>   "uisgid:", "False,", "usize:", "605693959,", "uisuid:", "False,",
>   "uisreg:", "True,", "upw_name:", "uroot,", "ugid:", "0,", "uischr:",
>   "False,", "uwusr:", "True,", "uxoth:", "False,", "uislnk:", "False,",
>   "unlink:", "1,", "uissock:", "False,", "urgrp:", "True,", "ugr_name:",
>   "uroot,", "upath:", "u/home/ec2-user/automate-20181020020209.aib,",
>   "uxusr:", "False,", "uatime:", "1540883969.7361338,", "uisdir:",
>   "False,", "uctime:", "1540883975.674141,", "uisblk:", "False,",
>   "uwgrp:", "False,", "uxgrp:", "False,", "udev:", "64768,", "uroth:",
>   "True,", "uisfifo:", "False,", "umode:", "u0644,", "urusr:",
>   "True}]"], "delta": "0:00:00.014548", "end": "2018-10-30
>   07:19:41.288141", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 113, "start":
>   "2018-10-30 07:19:41.273593", "stderr": "Error: UnknownError: accepts
>   between 0 and 1 arg(s), received 62", "stderr_lines": ["Error:
>   UnknownError: accepts between 0 and 1 arg(s), received 62"], "stdout":
>   "", "stdout_lines": []}   to retry, use: --limit
>   @/home/ec2-user/ANSIBLE/clusterOps/roles/chef-automatev2/defaults/main.retry

was able to get the dictionary item:

```
- hosts: chefclusterautomatev2
  remote_user: ec2-user
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  connection: ssh
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:

  - name: get aib filename
    find:
      paths: /home/ec2-user
    register: res

  - name: deploy chef-automatev2
    debug:
      msg: printing aib filename
    with_items: "{{ res.files | map(attribute='path') | first}}"
```

**Thanks to Matthew**
i get at playbook run:

```
TASK [deploy chef-automatev2] *************************************************************************
ok: [1.1.1.17] => (item=/home/ec2-user/automate-20181019225406.aib) => {
    "msg": "printing aib filename"
}
```

Now the question is how to use this object in "command" or "shell" ansible modules

Here is how I resolved the question of using the object in a shell command:

```
- hosts: localhost
  remote_user: a3x52zz
  connection: ssh
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:

  - name: get aib filename
    find:
      paths: /Users/a3x52zz/ansible-test
      file_type: "file"
      patterns: "automate*.aib"
    register: files_matched
  - debug:
      msg: "{{files_matched.files[1].path}}"

  - name: cat filename
    command: cat "{{files_matched.files[1].path}}"
```

Comment: Changed tag 'habitat' to 'chef-habitat'. Part of effort to split up ambiguous tag 'habitat'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to read the error message, you would see that `file_automate.files` does not contain a list of filenames but rather contains a list of python objects, likely as the result of calling `stat:`

```
  "cmd": [
    "sudo",
    "chef-automate",
    "deploy",
    "/home/ec2-user/config.toml",
    "--accept-terms-and-mlsa",
    "--skip-preflight",
    "--airgap-bundle",
    "/home/ec2-user/[{uuid: 0, uwoth: False, umtime: 1540882069.3233995, uinode: 82, uisgid: False, usize: 605693959, uisuid: False, uisreg: True, upw_name: uroot, ugid: 0, uischr: False, uwusr: True, uxoth: False, uislnk: False, unlink: 1, uissock: False, urgrp: True, ugr_name: uroot, upath: u/home/ec2-user/automate-20181020020209.aib, uxusr: False, uatime: 1540882068.8493989, uisdir: False, uctime: 1540882074.7854095, uisblk: False, uwgrp: False, uxgrp: False, udev: 64768, uroth: True, uisfifo: False, umode: u0644, urusr: True}]"
  ],
```

If you want just the list of filenames, `{{ file_automate.files | map(attribute="path") | list }}` should give that to you, although you'll want to omit the leading `/home/ec2-user/` because as one can see, the `path` field of that object in `files` is already fully qualified.

Comment: I want to get only the filename "automate-20181020020209.aib" is there a way get only that name?

Comment: my idea was to use regex  '^automate.*' and return one filename

Comment: I can't link directly to it, but the ["useful filters"](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#id8) section contains the description of the `basename` filter, resulting in `map(attribute="path") | map("basename") | list`; however, if you only one then use `| first` instead of `| list`

Comment: how would i use with_items: "{{ res.files | map(attribute='path') | first}}" as an object? i made additions to the question see ^^